# How to Initialize 8 hours in DataTime formate

Tags: c#

I want to initialize 8 hours in DateTime format.I tried like this

```
DateTime stayingTime = 8;
TimeSpan span = (stayingTime-runningTime);
```

I will get `runningTime` from some other source. I want to subtract that `runningTime` with 8 hours and display the answer in following format `hh:mm`

Comment: What is the type of `runningTime` is it `DateTime` or is it a `TimeSpan` ?

Comment: runningTime is DateTime type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`TimeSpan`-structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TimeSpan stayingTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
TimeSpan span = stayingTime - runningTime;
```

If you need it as `DateTime` you could use the [`TimeOfDay` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime stayingTime = new DateTime().AddHours(8);
TimeSpan span = stayingTime.TimeOfday - runningTime;
```

If you want to output it with `hh:mm`-format use [`TimeSpan.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
span.ToString("hh':'mm")
```